# Problem with fragment that uses a method of another class, Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have two different classes that i will show

```
public class Iniziale extends AppCompatActivity {

Button credits,gioca,giocamyquiz,newquestion;
TextView testo;
public boolean whatgame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_iniziale);

    gioca = findViewById(R.id.gioca);
    giocamyquiz = findViewById(R.id.giocamyquiz);
    newquestion= findViewById(R.id.newquestions);

    whatgame=true;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    gioca.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            whatgame=true;
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Iniziale.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });


    giocamyquiz.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            whatgame=false;
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Iniziale.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });
}


public boolean FragmentMethod() {
    return whatgame;
}
 }
```

and a fragment

```
 public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                               Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
       super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_activity, container, false);

    what=true;      //sceglie a quale quiz giocare

    what=((Iniziale) getActivity()).FragmentMethod();
```

I want use method FragmentMethod() in my Fragment class because I need the value of the whatgame variable. 
How the code is write it doesn't work.
In Iniziale class I have 2 buttons and based of what button i click I will modify my whatgame variable and modify some parameters in fragment class

Comment: try Your Code In 
onViewCreated  Not  In  onCreateView